# Pandas: How to group rows in a dataframe by a column, and then take the smallest n number of rows per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have this starting data set:

```
word1   word6   0.12    0.2
word1   word34  0.52    0.4
word1   word4   0.33    0.2
word1   word7   0.44    0.1
word2   word8   0.25    0.6
word2   word9   0.001   0.09
word2   word10  0.002   0.08
word2   word11  0.13    0.15
word3   word6   0.015   0.25
word3   word4   0.26    0.4
word3   word7   0.62    0.4
word3   word8   0.61    0.1
```

I want to group by column 0, and then return the rows by taking the top 2 per group, according to the third column. So here, the output should be:

```
word1   word6   0.12    0.2
word1   word4   0.33    0.2
word2   word9   0.001   0.09
word2   word10  0.002   0.08
word3   word6   0.015   0.25
word3   word4   0.26    0.4
```

In the case of equal scores, any one can be taken but that won't be an issue in this data set because in reality the numbers are given rounded to 7 decimal places.

I wrote this:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('test_file.txt',sep='\t',names=['query','hit','normalized_value','unnormalized_value'])
df = df.sort_values(['query','normalized_value']).groupby('normalized_value').head(2)
print(df)
```

And the output is:

```
    query     hit  normalized_value  unnormalized_value
0   word1   word6             0.120                0.20
2   word1   word4             0.330                0.20
3   word1   word7             0.440                0.10
1   word1  word34             0.520                0.40
5   word2   word9             0.001                0.09
6   word2  word10             0.002                0.08
7   word2  word11             0.130                0.15
4   word2   word8             0.250                0.60
8   word3   word6             0.015                0.25
9   word3   word4             0.260                0.40
11  word3   word8             0.610                0.10
10  word3   word7             0.620                0.40
```

...from what I can see it's just ordered the rows by the correct column, but it hasn't returned only the top two rows per group, which i said to do with `.head(2)`?

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Need group by column `query`, not `normalized_value`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['query','normalized_value']).groupby('query').head(2)
```